# Access and save Wordpress post title on external database

Tags: php, wordpress

Background: I have 2 website, Website B is the wordpress website. Website A and B are not on the same server.

What I want to achieve is to somehow have a script on website A to scan through website b and save the post title, post and URL to website A's database.

Website A: www.MyWebsite.com

Website B: blog.MyWebsite.com (Wordpress).

My plan at the moment is to connect directly into Website B's Db and save what I want but into Website's A DB but I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this where I don't have to connect to Website B's DB and just get the feed in XML

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds ?

Answer (score 0):

I would connect to Website B's database in one connection, then perform a query to get all the information you need. Then iterate through the results and save any data you want into an `Array`. Then take that Array data and connect to Website A's database to save it.

Hopefully this all made sense :)

Comment: @user742736 If I've solved your question please be sure to hit the check mark next to it, to mark it as solved :)